# Using inline assembler in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

I have few problems, my c++ program which have to detect which CPU I am using is having few errors, but I dont see them:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    char c1[4], c2[4], c3[4];


    __asm 
    {
        MOV EAX, 0
        CPUID
        MOV c1, EBX
        MOV c2, EDX
        MOV c3, ECX


    }

    printf("%.4s%.4s%.4s\n", c1, c2, c3);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem of mine?

Errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  3.cpp
1>d:\faks\arhitektorua\blok 1\3\3\3.cpp(16): error C2443: operand size conflict
1>d:\faks\arhitektorua\blok 1\3\3\3.cpp(17): error C2443: operand size conflict
1>d:\faks\arhitektorua\blok 1\3\3\3.cpp(18): error C2443: operand size conflict
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Use the [__cpuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx) function instead.

Comment: Suggestion:  for a C++ program, you should use C++ headers `<cstdio>` and `<cstdlib>` instead of C headers.

Comment: What happens if your CPU is MIPS or ARM?  Those instructions are x86.

Comment: You could probably get this to compile with `mov dword ptr c1, ebx` and so on.

Comment: Thank you guys it is fixed with other method. To be honest, with __cpuid method.